# Problems with rendering in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new in python kivy and I have some problems. I'm writing snake game with ScreenManager.On the main screen all work properly([main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVvAF.png)). On the game window I have this ([The game window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6vg7.png)). The game doesn't update several times per second as it must do. But if I write it without multiscreen it renders properly. Thus it's not the problem with game code. Here's the source code:

```
main.py:

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from random import randrange
from kivy.clock import Clock


SIZE = 40
SPEED = 5


class SnakeBody(Widget):

    size = (SIZE, SIZE)


class Food(Widget):

    size = (SIZE, SIZE)

    def move(self):
        self.x = randrange(SIZE, Window.width - SIZE, SIZE)
        self.y = randrange(int(Window.height / 2) + SIZE, Window.height - SIZE, SIZE)


class SnakeGame(Widget):

    direction = (SIZE, 0)
    snake_body = []
    snake_trail = []

    def add_body(self):

        body = SnakeBody()
        if len(self.snake_body) == 0:
            body.pos = (randrange(SIZE, Window.width - SIZE, SIZE),
                        randrange(int(Window.height / 2) + SIZE, Window.height - SIZE, SIZE))
        else:
            body.pos = self.snake_trail[-2]
        self.add_widget(body)
        self.snake_body.append(body)

    def new_game(self):

        for body_parts in self.snake_body:
            self.remove_widget(body_parts)

        self.snake_trail = []
        self.snake_body = []
        self.direction = (SIZE, 0)
        self.ids.food.move()
        self.add_body()

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):

        mx = touch.x - touch.opos[0]
        my = touch.y - touch.opos[1]

        if abs(mx) > abs(my) and mx > 0 and self.direction != [-SIZE, 0]:
            self.direction = [SIZE, 0]

        elif abs(mx) > abs(my) and mx < 0 and self.direction != [SIZE, 0]:
            self.direction = [-SIZE, 0]

        elif abs(mx) < abs(my) and my > 0 and self.direction != [0, -SIZE]:
            self.direction = [0, SIZE]

        elif abs(mx) < abs(my) and my < 0 and self.direction != [0, SIZE]:
            self.direction = [0, -SIZE]

    def refresh(self, dt):

        head = self.snake_body[0]
        head.pos[0] += self.direction[0]
        head.pos[1] += self.direction[1]

        new_pos = (head.pos[0], head.pos[1])
        self.snake_trail.append(new_pos)
        while len(self.snake_trail) > len(self.snake_body) + 1:
            del self.snake_trail[0]

        for i, body in enumerate(self.snake_body):
            if body is head:
                continue
            body.pos = self.snake_trail[i]

        if head.pos == self.ids.food.pos:
            self.ids.food.move()
            self.add_body()

        for body in self.snake_body:
            if body is not head and head.pos == body.pos:
                self.new_game()

        if not (0 <= head.pos[0] < Window.width) or \
           not (0 <= head.pos[1] < Window.height):
            self.new_game()


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class GameWindow(Screen):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("assets/GameStyle.kv")


class SnakeApp(App):

    def on_start(self):
        snakegame = SnakeGame()
        snakegame.new_game()
        Clock.schedule_interval(snakegame.refresh, 1 / SPEED)

    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SnakeApp()
    app.run()

kv file:

    #:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
    
    WindowManager:
        MainWindow:
        GameWindow:
    
    
    <MainWindow>:
        name: "MainWindow"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            BoxLayout:
                FloatLayout:
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: .25, .25, .25
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: 0, 0
                            size: root.width, root.height / 2
                        Color:
                            rgb: 0, 0, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: 0, root.height / 2
                            size: root.width, root.height / 2
                        Color:
                            rgb: 0, 0, 0
                        Line:
                            points: 0, root.height / 2, 0, root.height, root.width, root.height, root.width, root.height / 2, 0, root.height / 2
                            width: 2
                    Label:
                        text: "Snake\n"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        halign: "center"
                        font: "Calibri"
                        font_size: 60
                        color: 1, 0, 0, 1
                    Label:
                        text: "The game"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
                        halign: "center"
                        font: "Calibri"
                        font_size: 60
                        color: 0, 1, 0, 1
            AnchorLayout:
                Button:
                    text: "Let's play"
                    size_hint: .9, .9
                    on_press:
                        app.root.current = "GameWindow"
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
    
    <SnakeBody>:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 0
            Rectangle:
                size: root.size
                pos: root.pos
    
    <Food>:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0, 1, 0
            Rectangle:
                size: root.size
                pos: root.pos
    
    <SnakeGame>:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: Window.width, Window.height / 2
                pos: 0, Window.height / 2
            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0
            Line:
                points: 0, Window.height / 2, 0, Window.height, Window.width, Window.height, Window.width, Window.height / 2, 0, Window.height / 2
                width: 2
    
        Food:
            id: food
    
    <GameWindow>:
        name: "GameWindow"
    
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
    
            BoxLayout:
                SnakeGame:
    
            AnchorLayout:
                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: "center"
                    anchor_y: "top"
    
                    Button:
                        text: "UP"
                        size_hint: .3, .3
                        on_press:
                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: "center"
                    anchor_y: "bottom"
    
                    Button:
                        text: "DOWN"
                        size_hint: .3, .3
                        on_press:
                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: "right"
                    anchor_y: "center"
    
                    Button:
                        text: "RIGHT"
                        size_hint: .3, .3
                        on_press:
                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: "left"
                    anchor_y: "center"
    
                    Button:
                        text: "LEFT"
                    size_hint: .3, .3
                    on_press:
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: "left"
                anchor_y: "bottom"

                Button:
                    text: "Back"
                    size_hint: .25, .25
                    on_press:
                        app.root.current = "MainWindow"
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Comment: You can adjust your update frequency by changing your `SPEED` variable.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is the snake doesn't even appear on the game screen

Comment: In your `on_start()` method, you create a `SnakeGame` widget, but you never add it to the `GameWindow`.

Comment: "BoxLayout:
                SnakeGame:" in kv file

Comment: I see that now. But in your `on_start()` method you are creating a new instance of `SnakeGame` and scheduling calls to `refresh()` on that new instance. Unfortunately, the new instance of `SnakeGame` is not the instance that is in your `GameWindow`, so nothing you do with that instance will appear in your GUI.

Comment: Please format your code (mainly in `kvlang`) with proper indentation for easy access.

Comment: John, exactly. Maybe that is a problem I was looking for.